# An exercise on set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The type of exercise I'm about to speak of seems quite basic however I didn't have any exposure to it until recently so please provide me with some pointers on how to work it out.

Show that if the sets A, B and C satisfy the following relations simultaneously:

$A\cup B = C\\ 
   (A\cup C) \cap B = C\\ 
   (A \cap C) \cup B = A$

then they are the same.

Comment: For example, it is possible to read $B\subseteq A\subseteq C\subseteq B$ from the given statements (how?), hence equality must hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Asaf Karagila's answer and my last Logics course I understood how to solve this type of exercise. I have attached my solution down below in a picture however I intend to rewrite this answer using latex equations when I'll get some free time.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Recall that $X=Y$ if and only if $X\subseteq Y$ **and** $Y\subseteq X$.

Now using this we have that: $B\subseteq A\cup B\subseteq C$ from the first line; and since $C=B\cap (\text{something})$ we have that $C\subseteq B$. From those we have that $B=C$.

I am leaving it to you to show how $A=B$ as well, and to write a rigorous proof.